# 2D XNA Shooting Game

Tags: xna, c#, 2d

im doing a XNA game for a school project but im having trouble with the bullets. I can´t find any way to draw them or "invoque" them went i want. It is a modified Space Invaders that im trying to do. Sorry for my bad english. Help plz
PS: im using rectangles instead of vectors.

Comment: What *exactly* is your question? Where are you using "rectangles instead of vectors"? What do you mean by "invokes"? What have you tried that isn't working? Please edit the question to clarify. It's OK if your English is weak. We can usually deal with that, but we need to understand the question.

Comment: Instead of using vectores in images im using rectangles. I cant make the bullet appear when i press the key. and im having trouble in the bullet class because i cant find a way no shoot many at a tmie.

Comment: It sounds like you need to learn Object-Oriented Programming first. There are many tutorials. The first part of [our FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq) is a good place to start.

Comment: Rectangles instead of vectors? Vector as in Vector2D/3D?

Comment: Yes. Insted of using rectangles for images i use vectors

Comment: Sorry you're not able to get it figured out @André, unfortunately this isn't the place for discussion. You should check out the [FAQ], there you'll find some sites that are more discussion oriented and will allow you to get help with getting started.

Comment: Andre, Rectangles are typically used to draw images, and vectors to position them.

Answer (score 1):

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/gamedevelopment

the tutorial here should be more than enough to see you on your way